# How do I distribute my Jython app among the users?

Tags: jython

I have created a Jython app and I would like to distribute it to my friends. I don't want them to have to install Jython by themselves. They'll just have Java SE (JRE) installed and I want to pack my application in a way that they will be able to run it just by double clicking on a file. The application is a desktop GUI app.

I was just wondering if I can put my application files in the Jython directory, create a batch file with "java -jar jython.jar myapp.py" and distribute the entire folder. Will that work for all? Why it might fail?

Thanks

Comment: It works for me! But I'm wondering if it'll work for others too. Also my app doesn't use any Python modules. Just SWING, what'll happen if I use Python modules with the app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](http://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonFaq/DistributingJythonScripts) Jython Wiki page is covers the various distribution options.

The relevant section is **"What's a really easy way to distribute my app as a single jar?"** however, it will require creating a Java wrapper and some JAR file manipulation. With the Jython standalone JAR, you got about an ~8MB file to distribute.